# AWS: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam, botocore

I am running a few jobs in AWS Batch. I have brought over my .aws credentials file and config file for each container.

Here is the code I'm trying to run.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
session = boto3.Session()
client = session.client('s3')

dse_input_s3_objects = client.list_objects(
    Bucket='mybucket',
    Prefix='mypath/'
)
```

When I run the code locally, I have no issues, but when I try to run it in Batch I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

I am using the following batch service role

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html

One thing to note, in Batch I am using a conda environment, so I'm not sure if that would cause any issue in accessing the credentials? Though, reading the error, it seems like it has successfully located the credentials.

Any ideas on why this isn't working? Do I need to add something to the batch service role?

EDIT:

Here is my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListPermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "GetPermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PutPermission",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The IAM role you linked does not include any permissions to S3, which is what you are trying to access. Does the bucket policy allow the role?

Comment: I just added my bucket policy to the question in an edit.

Comment: When you grant access to an account, the IAM role within that account must have S3 permissions in it's role policy.